# How to back up oracle database using java?

Tags: java, oracle11g

I'm currently using Oracle 11g R2 express edition. How can I back up my database using java application? Is it possible?

Comment: If you have a jdbc Driver for that database, anything is possible. Do some research and come back.

Comment: Research failed before today evening. I didn't get any way to do it. How can I do it? I have JDBC Oracle driver

Comment: lets first ask why do you want to do it from java ? and is it necessary for you to use jdbc as you can run a simple export command from your program

Comment: Just find out what Oracle command you have to send to the database to back it up, then execute those commands with your driver.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean with "backup". If you want to create a dump of the database, you can do that using the `dbms_datapump` package.

As it is a regular PL/SQL package it can easily be called through JDBC. The easiest thing is probably to send an anonymous PL/SQL block as a single statement.

Something like this:

```
String sql = 
  "DECLARE \n" +
  "  handle NUMBER; \n" +
  "BEGIN \n" +
  "  handle := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN(operation => 'EXPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name => USER||'_DUMP', version => 'COMPATIBLE'); \n" +
  "  dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => handle, filename => 'db_backup', directory => 'EXPDP_DIR'); \n" +
  "  dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(handle, 'SCHEMA_LIST', '''SCOTT'''); \n" +
  "  dbms_datapump.start_job(handle); \n" +
  "  dbms_datapump.detach(handle); \n" +
  "END;";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sql);
```

Note that I left out any error handling. Alternatively you can call each `dbms_datapump` procedure individually (using a `CallableStatement`)

The dump will will be written on the server, not on the client!

For more details please refer to the manual:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_datpmp.htm

Answer (score 0):

Well, generally you can, because you can extract data and store SQL structure (tables, constraints, indices etc.)
You may find useful [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/admin.102/b25107/backrest.htm)
You can also use YAML format to store data.

Comment: How can I do this with java?

Comment: First, take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450399/which-java-yaml-library-should-i-use.

Comment: and then you can store your data according to your needs